# How to use Javascript/JQuery make REST request with X509 certificate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure

I ask this question because when I use Azure REST API, it require a client certificate.
In C# I can write the code like this:

```
 **X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certs = certificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, 
            certThumbprint, false);**

        if (certs.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find the certificate with thumbprint:" + certThumbprint);
            return;
        }

        certificateStore.Close();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
            new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/" + subscriptionId + "/services/hostedservices"));

        request.Method = "POST";
        **request.ClientCertificates.Add(certs[0]);**
```

But how should I make sample request in JS?

Comment: One option would be to have your js hit an api on your server that makes the request using C#

Comment: Is it for a Windows 8 App or regular web application?

Comment: regular web application

Comment: So yes, in normal Web Application you cannot handle X.509 certificates and you cannot call the Azure Management Service directly. Event the Management portal is using Proxy and not calling the Management REST API directly.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't use pure (browser based) JavaScript / jQuery to program against Azure REST Management API. And there are couple of reasons for that. First and foremost is that Azure REST Management does not support CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). Other one is authentication - there is no way to work with X.509 in browser based JavaScript.